# Setting Page.EnableEventValidation on Page_Init

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a user control in which I have successfully set `Page.EnableEventValidation = false` in the `Page_Init` event in the codebehind (in order to render the page markup to a string):

**MyControl.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{  
    if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null
        && Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == btnPrint.ClientID.Replace("_", "$"))
    {
        Page.EnableEventValidation = false;
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to duplicate this functionality on a separate page (this time in `runat=server` script tags)...

**MyPage.aspx**

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)        
    {  
        if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null
            && Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] ==
            btnDownloadPDF.ClientID.Replace("_", "$"))
        {
            Page.EnableEventValidation = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

... I get the following error:

> The 'EnableEventValidation' property can only be set in the page
>   directive or in the  configuration section.

Now, in my first example, I was receiving this error when originally attempting to do this on `Page_Load`; however, it seems that you *can* disable event validation programmatically as long as it's done during (or before) `Page_Init`. Unfortunately the same does not work in my second example.

Why does this work in one scenario and not the other? Is it related to the fact that the code is not in a codebehind?

Comment: Generally using `Page.EnableEventValidation = false` is a bad idea. Instead you should look at `Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally using `Page.EnableEventValidation = false` is a bad idea, for security reasons.

Instead you should look at `Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation`

For example:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(btnDownloadPDF.UniqueID);
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

This will register the event reference and allow the event to fire. Then you can leave `Page.EnableEventValidation = true`.

Check [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223397.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) from MSDN.